# Test Accept-language in my browser

Tags: asp.net, html, windows-7

How can I change my system configuration so that I can control what is sent in header in key: Accept-Language?

Thank You very much for help

Comment: That depends on which browser you use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Firefox:

- Tools->Options
- Click Content
- Under Languages click "Choose"
- Under Languages select a language
- Move that language to the top

That language should now be sent to the server with the accept-language header.

Answer (score 5):

In Google Chrome 16:

- Wrench icon to open menu
- Click the "Options" menu item
- Enter "lang" in the search field
- Click the "Settings for Languages and..." button
- Use drag and drop to re-arrange the languages or click the "Add" button to add new ones.

The top language is the one that ususally counts (the most).